# Custom ComboBox with Horizontal line in DropDown

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I want to create a Custom ComboBox in which the DropDown contains the Horizontal Line or you can say HRule immediate after the First Item. here I am providing you the image For that you can see i have used paint to draw the HRule i want component similar like that. Please provide me valuable Links or code for that. Here is the Image.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Have @ nice Day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer : [How to add a separator to your ComboBox](http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2007/08/27/how-to-add-a-separator-to-your-combobox/)